# Product attribute to show inside of static block on product page?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7, static-block

I have a magento template which has placed some static blocks on the product view pages. I have created some additional product attributes such as "product compatibility" for example, and would like to display this product attribute within a static block on the product page. That is, for each product you look at, the product attribute content will be different, but the position on the page will be the same because its within the static block.

I have tried using a tag such as

`{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/compatibility.phtml"}}`

within my static block, but it does not seem to do anything all and just displays that code on the frontend. I have turned off the wysiwyg for the editor(s), and have created a file named compatibility.phtml and just filled it with the test php code of:

`<?php echo 'I am working!' ?>`

I dont know if getting it to look t a file like this is even needed at all in order to grab the product attribute data though.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is possible but is a little bit complicated, if you are not a developer, besides any custom attribute can be displayed on product view pages without any static block in Additional Information section. You only need to create attribute, set "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to Yes and assign that attribute to an "Attribute sets".

Comment: I was able to do that, however but then it displays the attribute name and reduces the space for the attribute content. I liked this possibility because it game me the ability to change the tab/section name instead of it being "additional information". I might have to just find a way to butcher the css to get the same result?